# Как присвоить значение переменной результата the_content() без отображения контента на страницу

Tags: wordpress

Как присвоить значение переменной результата the_content() без вывода его на страницу.

get_the_content() -  не подходит, так как хоть он присваивает контент переменной, но там пропадают все тэги html, всё плывёт и не имеет того же вида, как при вызове the_content().

Есть такое решение???

$var = the_content(); // значение поста не должно появиться на сайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать буферизацию php.

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

А можно обойтись и функциями WordPress.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
```

Просто `get_the_content()` не работает, потому что к нему надо применить фильтры.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!!!